# Underscore template, adding a list into a single array?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have a template, which works fine but I am trying to build an array with the final goal of getting a total of those values.

So my template gives me the following list of values,

```
    10
    23
    14
    1
```

ect, for each value that is in my database, which loops around fine. But I want a total from this list, which I have done in the row but this goes over each row in the database. So what my aim was (and please tell me if there is a better method of doing this) was to build this into a single array by pushing each value into a new array within the template, then adding the array up, giving me a grand total.

So my template looks like this,

```
<script type="text/template" id="TimesheetData">
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.jobtitle  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.mon  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.tue  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.wed  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.thu  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.fri  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.sat  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.sun  %>">

  <span>Weekly total : <span class="TimeSheetWeekly<%= Timesheetrow.index %>"></span></span>

<%
    var WeeklyArray = [Timesheetrow.mon, Timesheetrow.tue, Timesheetrow.wed, Timesheetrow.thu, Timesheetrow.fri, Timesheetrow.sat, Timesheetrow.sun];
    var WeeklyTotals = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < WeeklyArray.length; i++) {
        WeeklyTotals += WeeklyArray[i] << 0;
    }

    _.defer(function(){ 
        var WeeklyTotalTag = '.TimeSheetWeekly'+ Timesheetrow.index;
        $( WeeklyTotalTag ).html(WeeklyTotals); 
    }) 


%>

</script>
```

But when I try to use `.zip` or `.map` I can not seem to build the array. It just seems to put each value into its own array and not a total array?

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

- Please let me know if I have not explained myself clearly, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/253f2vdb/)

I used [reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) to calculate sum of array.

```
<%= _.reduce(_.values(_.pick(Timesheetrow, 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')), function(a, b) {return a + b}, 0) %>
```

Full template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="TimesheetData">
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.jobtitle  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.mon  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.tue  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.wed  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.thu  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.fri  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.sat  %>">        
  <input type="type" name="data[Timesheetrow][<%= Timesheetrow.index %>][jobtitle]" value="<%= Timesheetrow.sun  %>">

  <span>Weekly total : <span class="TimeSheetWeekly<%= Timesheetrow.index %>">
    <%= _.reduce(_.values(_.pick(Timesheetrow, 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')), function(a, b) {return a + b}, 0) %>
  </span></span>

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I don't think I was clear with my question. I have the weekly total working without any problem. But I need a total for each mon, tue, ect for the whole loop. The will depend on how many jobs the user adds into the system